# How do I loop background music when the file is a quicktime (.mov) file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get some music which I have trimmed at certain points to play in the background of my personal webpage. However, the file is a QuickTime file now becuase when I trimmed the original mp3 file it turned it into a QuickTime file. I have provided what I have tried below. If someone could help out with this it would be much appreciated!

```
$('body').append('<audio loop autoplay volume="0" id="audio-player"><source src="PortfolioMusicFinalVersion.mov" type="audio/quicktime"></audio>');
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio-player");
        audio.volume = 0.2;
```

I am also using GitHub to host the website so maybe the problem is putting in the right directory to the file if that is the case then the code below should work. However, I am still unable to make it work.

```
$('body').append('<audio loop autoplay volume="0" id="audio-player"><source src="username.github.io/html/music/PortfolioMusicFinalVersion.mov" type="audio/quicktime"></audio>');
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio-player");
        audio.volume = 0.2;
```

Comment: An MP3 doesn't just "turn into" a MOV file by trimming it. Additionally, there is no support for MOV in modern web browsers. The solution is to keep it an MP3, as it was in the first place.

Comment: I would simply create a new file, starting again from the original audio file, and this time saving it as an *audio*  file. One (free) app to do it with is Audacity: https://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Johannes!